# Simple Word Wrap Function Last Line Problem

Tags: c++, word-wrap

I have a function that takes a long string and breaks into smaller strings and adds them to an array so that they can be outputted in a nicer looking paragraph. It works fine except for the last line doesn't output. How would I get it to output? Here's the code:

```
void WordWrap(string inputString, string formatedAr[], const int SIZE)
{
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned int index;
    unsigned int word;
    unsigned int max = 65;
    string outWord;
    string outLine;

    length = inputString.length();
    outWord = "";
    outLine = "";
    word = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        formatedAr[i] = "";
    }

    for(index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        if(inputString[index] != ' ')
        {
            outWord += inputString[index];
        }
        else
        {
            if(outLine.length() + outWord.length() > max)
            {
                formatedAr[word] = outLine;
                word++;
                outLine.clear();
            }
            outLine += outWord + " ";
            outWord.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got some sample input? Show us a testcase on ideone.com

Comment: You don't check against `SIZE` when inserting into `formatedAr[]`. Maybe use `vector` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only write into `formatedAr` when adding a character would make the current line too long. You also need to write the remnant into `formatedAr` when you've finished parsing the input string.

Try putting `formatedAr[word] = outLine;` after the `for` loop finishes.

Comment: This works, but it still doesn't get the last word because it's doing that `outWord.clear()` which is necessary every time except the last time. Any idea what would be a good way to have it do the clear every time but the last time? Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Michael: But you do `outLine += outWord + " "` before you do `outWord.clear()`, so the word is not lost - it should be in the `outLine`. There's another small problem - unnecessary space after the last word, but that's something different.

Comment: @Rafal: That makes sense, do you know why the last word is not outputting then?

Comment: @Michael: No idea. Maybe it went into the missing last line by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

If I understand it correctly, you want to split a sentence into different words, so instead of doing this:

```
for(index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        if(inputString[index] != ' ')
        {
            outWord += inputString[index];
        }
```

...

why don't you use streams:

```
string s(inputString);
istringstream iss(s);
vector<string> words;
copy (istream_iterator(iss),istream_iterator(),back_inserter(words));
```

Comment: `istream_iterator` needs a type argument.